# Show that each composite function $f_i \circ f_j$ is one of the given functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm just going through the problems that I got wrong on my discrete math exam, and I was not sure how to do this one. How would I go about making this chart? The chart has $f_1, \dots, f_5$ going across the top and down the side. I already got the question wrong, just want to know how to do it, in case it comes up again.

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and define $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5 \colon A \to A$ as follows:
\begin{align}
f_1 &= \{(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)\} \\
f_2 &= \{(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\} \\
f_3 &= \{(1,2),(2,1),(3,3)\} \\
f_4 &= \{(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\} \\
f_5 &= \{(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)\}
\end{align}
Show that each composite function $f_i\circ f_j$ is one of the given functions, or the identity, by completing a table. Find the inverse of those six functions that have inverses.

Comment: Changing the second f_i to $f_j$ is a substantial change that shouldn't have gone without input from the OP.

Comment: Yes, make a square table with the $f_i$ indexing the rows and columns. The entry for row $f_1$ and column $f_2$ will be $f_1\circ f_2 = \{(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\} = f_4$, and the entry with row $f_2$ and column $f_1$ will be $f_2\circ f_1 = \{(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)\} = f_5$ and so on...

Comment: What was the math behind this? f1∘f2={(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)}

Comment: @EricStucky “The table has $f_1,\dots,f_5$ going across the top and down the side”; I think that all compositions are to be taken into account.

Comment: @JebusCrust To compute $f_1\circ f_2$, you just have to say where $1$, $2$, and $3$ get sent. So, the notation $f_1\circ f_2$ means "do $f_2$ then $f_1$. Let's just look at where $1$ goes: $f_2$ takes 1 to 3 (that is the meaning of $(1,3)$), and then $f_1$ takes 3 to 2 (that is the meaning of $(3,2)$), so $f_1\circ f_2$ takes 1 to 2 (which is the meaning of $(1,2)$).

Comment: Would that mean that when we have 2 of the same (f1 o f1), it would be equal to f1?

Comment: since $(1,3)\in f_2$ this means $f_2(1)=3$. Similarly $f_1(3)=2$. Hence $(f_1\circ f_2)(1)=f_1(f_2(1))=f_1(3)=2$, that is $(f_1\circ f_2)(1)=2$. So $(1,2)\in f_1\circ f_2$. You may verify whether  $(f_1\circ f_2)(2)=3$ and whether  $(f_1\circ f_2)(3)=1$, which would show that also $(2,3)\in f_1\circ f_2$ and $(3,1)\in f_1\circ f_2$, and hence $f_1\circ f_2=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\}$.

Comment: It wouldn't mean that. You may veruify that $f_1\circ f_1=Id=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$, and that  $f_4\circ f_4=f_5$.

Comment: I figured that part out, now I just don't know how to do the inverse part of the question

Comment: for the inverse, switch left and right elements of each pair. For example $f_4(3)=1$, hence the inverse $f_4^{-1}(1)=3$. So $(3,1)\in f_4$, hence $(1,3)\in f_4^{-1}$. If $f_4=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\}$ then $f_4^{-1}=\{(2,1),(3,2),(1,3)\}=\{(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)=f_5$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f_0=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ is the identity map, the six maps $\{f_0,f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5\}$ are *six* bijective maps $A\to A$.

Since $|A|=3$, there are exactly $6=3!$ bijective maps $A\to A$, so the above set is the set of all *permutations* of $A$. Since the composition of two bijective maps is a bijective map, $f_i\circ f_j$ must belong to the set for any $i,j$, with $0\le i,j\le 5$.

You can fill in the composition table by hand. Some of the compositions are here:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
& f_0 & f_1 & f_2 & f_3 & f_4 & f_5 \\
\hline
f_0 &  &  &  &  &  & \\
f_1 &  &  &  &  &  & \\
f_2 &  & f_5 &  &  &  & \\
f_3 &  &  &  &  &  & \\
f_4 &  &  & f_1 &  &  & \\
f_5 &  &  &  &  &  & 
\end{array}
$$

Comment: The part you explained makes sense to me, but I still do not understand how you are filling in that chart?

Comment: @JebusCrust Composition of maps; $f_2\circ f_1(1)=f_2(1)=3$, $f_2\circ f_1(2)=f_2(3)=1$, $f_2\circ f_1(3)=f_2(2)=2$; therefore $f_2\circ f_1=f_5$.

Answer (score 0):

In cycle notation:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&f_1=(23)\\
&f_2=(13)\\
&f_3=(12)\\
&f_4=(123)\\
&f_5=(132)\\
\end{alignat}
By "completing a table etc." they mean to explicty prove that:
$$\forall i,j\in A, \exists k\in A \text{ such that } f_if_j=f_k, \text{ or otherwise } f_if_j=()$$
In fact (composition is right to left):
\begin{alignat}{1}
&f_1^2=()\\
&f_1f_2=(123)=f_4\\
&f_1f_3=(132)=f_5\\
&f_1f_4=(13)=f_2\\
&f_1f_5=(12)=f_3\\
\\
&f_2f_1=(132)=f_5\\
&f_2^2=()\\
&f_2f_3=(123)=f_4\\
&f_2f_4=(12)=f_3\\
&f_2f_5=(23)=f_1\\
\\
&f_3f_1=(123)=f_4\\
&f_3f_2=(132)=f_5\\
&f_3^2=()\\
&f_3f_4=(23)=f_1\\
&f_3f_5=(13)=f_2\\
\\
&f_4f_1=(12)=f_3\\
&f_4f_2=(23)=f_1\\
&f_4f_3=(13)=f_2\\
&f_4^2=(132)=f_5\\
&f_4f_5=()\\
\\
&f_5f_1=(12)=f_3\\
&f_5f_2=(23)=f_1\\
&f_5f_3=(13)=f_2\\
&f_5f_4=()\\
&f_5^2=(123)=f_4\\
\end{alignat}
Therefore, every $f_i$ has inverse; in particular, $f_{1,2,3}$ are self-inverses ("involutions"), whereas $f_4$ and $f_5$ are inverses each other.